# Java interface types or how do you use interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, software-design

It's a rather theoretical question, but what kind of interfaces does java have?
For example, I know two of them:

- **marker** interfaces (e.g. `Serializable`, no methods defined, is similar to class-level annotations)
- **functional** interfaces (e.g. `Runnable`, defines only one method)

Are there any more?

**UPDATE**

It might have been a better way to ask the question like this: in java, what do you use interfaces for? Besides the following ones:

- defining a "**contract**" for implementing classes ("standard" way)
- **marking** classes (e.g. for the JVM)
- using for **lambda expressions**
- using to implement "**traits**"

**UPDATE**

I'm not looking for the answer to "why/when/how to use interfaces for defining contracts" (e.g. the "standard" way, how interfaces are ment to be used initially); I'm looking for any other ways how people are using it (e.g. for marking, traits, etc.)

Comment: An interface is a collection of 0 or more predefined method declarations for you to implement to satisfy the interface.You can find some more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: I've checked the link, but did not see anything about marker or functional interfaces, or generally, about the different types of interfaces ...

Comment: Fundamentallym they are no differences. Marker-interfaces are interfaces without any methods declared, i.e. they only "mark" some functionality (like `Serializable` or `Cloneable`). Each interface defining only one method can be seen as a functional interface, i.e. it can be implemented with a lambda-expression (you can find more about lambdas and functional interfaces [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)). You could split up interfaces further, but this leads to design patterns and is most probably not, what you are looking / asking for.

Comment: There are nice dogs, brown dogs, and playful dogs.  Are there any more?  Same for interfaces.  "marker" and "functional" are just adjectives, not categories in any standard taxonomy.

Comment: Updated my question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

There are many interfaces in java for different things. Some for just marking other classes like for example ´Serializable´

Really listing them doesn't make sense as you will often learn them on a need to know basis when you need to work with an interface to accomplish something.

[Read more about interfaces here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)